# How to add store credit to order programmatically Magento?

Tags: php, mysql, magento, magento-1.9.1

I am creating a script in which I am getting order data from third party. Everything is working fine, the issue is that I am unable to add storecredit to order. Is there any way to add store credit in order and substract them from grandtotal. Here is my code:

```
$order->setDiscountAmount($total_discount)->setBaseDiscountAmout($total_discount);
                $order->setSubtotal($total_amount)->setBaseSubtotal($total_amount);
                $order->setGrandTotal($total_amount-$total_discount)->setBaseGrandTotal($total_amount-$total_discount);
                $order->save();
```

Comment: Great, so what is the error you see when you run this code? Can you give us some sample input/output for how it should work when it's working: and can you let us know what you've tried to make it work yourself? (including any non-working examples)? do we don't duplicate your effort?

Comment: @TarynEast i am not getting any error, the orders are saving perfectly, but i am not able to add store credit, i need guidance for adding storecredit, suppose grand total 2200 and someone has store credit 10 then it should be shown in magento admin order and grand total will be 2200-10

Comment: and instead you get... ?

Comment: i think you are not getting my point, i just need to insert store credit in order total.

Comment: I think you are not getting mine. There is an established expectation for questions in Stack Overflow. If you don't follow it (or can't), then your question is liable to go unanswered. I am trying to help you to get your question answered... by following that established rule. Here's the full description if you like: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to do the same thing, and looking at the comments, I think it's ridiculous that this thread just died. Either you are here to help and assist, or you are not. If the thread dies because you enforce a question standard, is that helpful?

Here is how to do it.

```
$balance = Mage::getModel('enterprise_customerbalance/balance')
            ->setWebsiteId(Mage::app()->getStore($quote->getStoreId())->getWebsiteId())
            ->setCustomerId($quote->getCustomerId())
            ->loadByCustomer();

        if ($balance && $balance >= $creditTobeUsed) {
            $quote->setUseCustomerBalance(true);
            $quote->setCustomerBalanceInstance($balance);
        }

        $quote->collectTotals();
        $quote->save();
```

Enterprise_CustomerBalance_Block_Checkout_Onepage_Payment_Additional has some methods which you can use

Finally, when credit is applied, at the checkout make sure that you set the following

```
<input type="hidden" type="text" value="1"  name="payment[use_customer_balance]" class="input-text" />
```